# StackOverflowError in java_lang_Class$isArray.call() when using Groovy's JsonBuilder

Tags: grails, groovy, jsonbuilder

My Grails application and its integration tests are throwing a StackOverflowError when I try to use Groovy's JsonBuilder class on my domain classes.  My code looks like this:

```
String result = new JsonBuilder(new MyDomainClass())
```

Since I found articles about JsonBuilder looping on self-references, I stripped down the domain class to almost nothing:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp.myarea
class MyDomainClass { }
```

but the stack overflow still reproduces.  Here's the kicker.  If I move the declaration of MyDomainClass out of its normal location and into the file where the unit test lives (i.e., *take it out of its package*), JsonBuilder works.

Stack trace below.  Any help here?

Thanks,
BGU

```
 java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallStaticSite(CallSiteArray.java:62)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallSite(CallSiteArray.java:159)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at java_lang_Class$isArray.call(Unknown Source)
at groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(JsonOutput.groovy:135)
at groovy.json.JsonOutput$toJson.callStatic(Unknown Source)
at groovy.json.JsonOutput$_toJson_closure2.doCall(JsonOutput.groovy:158)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor974.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.callClosureForMapEntry(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:3870)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2426)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2443)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$61.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(JsonOutput.groovy:154)
at groovy.json.JsonOutput$toJson$0.callStatic(Unknown Source)
at groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(JsonOutput.groovy:146)
at groovy.json.JsonOutput$toJson.callStatic(Unknown Source)
at groovy.json.JsonOutput$_toJson_closure1.doCall(JsonOutput.groovy:138)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor978.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:425)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2157)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2128)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$59.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(JsonOutput.groovy:138)
at groovy.json.JsonOutput$toJson.callStatic(Unknown Source)
at groovy.json.JsonOutput$_toJson_closure2.doCall(JsonOutput.groovy:158)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor974.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.callClosureForMapEntry(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:3870)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2426)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2443)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$61.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(JsonOutput.groovy:154)
at groovy.json.JsonOutput$toJson$0.callStatic(Unknown Source)
at groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(JsonOutput.groovy:146)
at groovy.json.JsonOutput$toJson.callStatic(Unknown Source)
at groovy.json.JsonOutput$_toJson_closure1.doCall(JsonOutput.groovy:138)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor978.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:425)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2157)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2128)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$59.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(JsonOutput.groovy:138)
at groovy.json.JsonOutput$toJson.callStatic(Unknown Source)
at groovy.json.JsonOutput$_toJson_closure2.doCall(JsonOutput.groovy:158)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor974.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.callClosureForMapEntry(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:3870)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2426)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2443)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$61.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(JsonOutput.groovy:154)
at groovy.json.JsonOutput$toJson$0.callStatic(Unknown Source)
at groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(JsonOutput.groovy:146)
at groovy.json.JsonOutput$toJson.callStatic(Unknown Source)
at groovy.json.JsonOutput$_toJson_closure1.doCall(JsonOutput.groovy:138)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor978.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:425)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2157)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2128)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$59.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(JsonOutput.groovy:138)
at groovy.json.JsonOutput$toJson.callStatic(Unknown Source)
at groovy.json.JsonOutput$_toJson_closure2.doCall(JsonOutput.groovy:158)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor974.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1082)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1106)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:906)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.callClosureForMapEntry(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:3870)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2426)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.collect(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2443)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$61.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)...
```

Answer (score 1):

I stepped into the code a little bit, and `JsonBuilder` has a number of type checks to decide how the object should be written. In case of the domain class it matches `Iterable`. It then tries to loop over it and write each item etc.

Strange thing is that `next` after casting the object to `Iterable` returns the objects itself.... causing and endless loop.

It works if I write the following (still fails without the explicit cast):

```
String result = new JsonBuilder((Map)(new MyDomainClass().properties))
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful tip.  Unfortunately many of the values in my 'properties' map are, themselves, domain classes.  Thus I just get the stack overflow in a different place.

I'm new to Groovy, so I am wondering if JsonBuilder is the right tool for the job?  Maybe there is a more class- (versus map-) friendly JSON generator floating around?  Or is there a desire to get the bug you mentioned fixed?  

I'm open to suggestions.